# creating events for newly created windows form control (in wpf)

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a notifyicon in a wpf project using this code:

```
Dim ni = New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
Private Sub btnsystemtray_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles btnTaskbar.MouseUp
    ni.Visible = True
    ni.Icon = My.Resources.myicon
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

I was able to make it work which minimizes the window to system tray. However, I don't know how to make a click event for the notifyicon which should show the window. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't have design time support for NotifyIcon, so you'll have to do it in code.

```
Private WithEvents ni As New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon

Private Sub ni_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ni.Click
  Me.Show()
End Sub
```

Be sure to manually dispose the NotifyIcon on exit to remove it from the system tray:

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Closed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
  ni.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 - make sure to call ni.Visible = False in ni_Click if you want to get rid of the icon in the tray after the window is restored

Comment: Don't use the Closed event of a Form, it is [obsolute since .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed.aspx), use the [FormClosed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) instead.

Comment: Also, call the `ni.Dispose()` in the `Dispose()` of your `MainWindow` (because the MainWindow isn't necessarily disposed when you close it ... and thus its resources shouldn't yet get disposed).